# Thread local storage does not work using threads created with clone()

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, c11, thread-local-storage

The program below creates ten threads using Linux's `clone()` system call. The static variable `tls` has the C11 `thread_local` attribute. The threads execute the `child_func` function, which just increments the `tls` variable and stores the incremented value in the location pointed to by the argument `arg`. The incremented values are stored, one for each thread, in the array `tlsvals`. The `main` function waits for the threads to finish and then prints the values of the ten instances of the `tls` variable. (I have skipped error checking and the freeing of the allocated stacks in this version of the code, to keep the example brief.)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <threads.h>        /* For thread_local. */

#define NTHREADS 10

static thread_local int tls = 0;

static int child_func(void *arg)
{
  tls++;
  *((int *)arg) = tls;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int tlsvals[NTHREADS];
  for (int n = 0; n < NTHREADS; n++) {
    const int STACK_SIZE = 65536;
    if (clone(child_func, malloc(STACK_SIZE) + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, tlsvals+n) == -1) {
      perror("clone");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  int ret, status;
  while ((ret = wait(&status)) != -1)
    ;

  for (int *p = tlsvals; p < tlsvals + NTHREADS; p++)
    printf("The value of tls is %d\n", *p);

  return 0;
}
```

Since the `tls` variable is marked `thread_local`, I expected the program to print ten lines of `The value of tls is 1`, since each thread increments the variable once from its initial zero value. Instead I get the following output:

```
The value of tls is 1
The value of tls is 3
The value of tls is 2
The value of tls is 4
The value of tls is 5
The value of tls is 6
The value of tls is 7
The value of tls is 8
The value of tls is 9
The value of tls is 10
```

So it seems the `tls` variable is not thread-local at all, but shared by all the threads, and each thread increments the same variable.

The code was compiled with GCC version 9.1.0 on x86_64 using the following command line:

```
gcc -O2 -Wall -std=c11 tfoo.c -o tfooc
```

I also tried using the GCC specific `__thread` attribute instead of `thread_local`, with the same result.

Looking at the assembly produced by GCC, I can see that the variable is accessed via the `%fs` register, as it should be:

```
child_func:
.LFB24:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    %fs:tls@tpoff, %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    movl    %eax, %fs:tls@tpoff
    movl    %eax, (%rdi)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

What am I doing wrong, or is there a bug in the implementation of `thread_local` in Gcc?

Comment: You are not creating new threads, but processes that just share the same memory. What makes you think that `thread_local` should work for them? You'd probably need to use `CLONE_THREAD` for that.

Comment: @JensGustedt So what is the exact difference between "threads" and "processes that share the same memory"? I tried adding `CLONE_THREAD` (and `CLONE_SIGHAND`, since `CLONE_THREAD` requires it), but no change.

Comment: Did you read the detailed description of `CLONE_THREAD` in the manual page of `clone`? Generally that manual page doesn't say much about `thread_local`. But perhaps you should first tell us why `pthread_create`  or `thrd_create` are not good enough for you.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes I read the description of `CLONE_THREAD`, and it doesn't say anything about thread local storage. This whole exercise started with me trying to understand how TLS is implemented on Linux, and for that I needed to create some threads, preferably at a low level. I now understand that you have to use `CLONE_SETTLS` and for that you have to use the raw kernel interface to `clone`, since the library function does not expose the `newtls` parameter, using which you have to pass a different value for the `%fs` register (on x86_64) the for each thread.